# How to make a div on second click to close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have like 3 blocks and they work perfectly on PC Version, they close and open on click but I have a problem with the mobile version, when i click on one of them it opens but it doesn't close, it closes just if i click on the other block. And if I click again on the same block that is already opened, it just re-opens it. I can't close it, I don't know why. Any help, please!!

```
<div class="section stats tint">
                <div class="container w-container">
                    <div class="hero-overlay-row w-row">
                            <div class="stats-column w-col w-col-4">
                                <a class="hero-overlay-block-1 w-inline-block" href="#">
                                    <div class="hero-overlay-number">У</div>
                                    <div class="hero-overlay-block-title">УЗО</div>
                                    <p class="link-block-paragraph">Ги брани и прикажува ставовите на учениците.</p>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <div class="block-uzo">
                            <h3>УЗО</h3>
                            <p>
                                Училишната Заедница на СУГС Орце Николов претставува легитимно тело составено од претседателите на сите класови,
                                со свое посебно претседателство и организација, основано со цел да ги брани и прикажува ставовите на учениците,
                                да воспоставува легитимна врска помеѓу учениците и училишните служби. Да организира настани, и покренува иницијативи
                                за подобрување на образованието.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="stats-column w-col w-col-4">
                        <a class="hero-overlay-block-2 w-inline-block" href="#">
                        <div class="hero-overlay-number">М</div>
                        <div class="hero-overlay-block-title">Мисија</div>
                            <p class="link-block-paragraph">Комуникација и соработка со училишните служби.</p>
                        </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="block-misija">
                            <h3>Мисија</h3>
                            <p>
                                УЗО  ги застапува потребите и интересите на учениците, преку комуникација и соработка со училишните служби и истовремено
                                поттикнува и придонесува личен развој, преку вклучување на учениците во училишни и вонучилишни активности.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="last stats-column w-col w-col-4">
                        <a class="hero-overlay-block-3 w-inline-block" href="#">
                        <div class="hero-overlay-number">В</div>
                        <div class="hero-overlay-block-title">Визија</div>
                            <p class="link-block-paragraph">Подобрување на образованието.</p>
                            </a></div>

                        <div class="block-vizija">
                            <h3>Визија</h3>
                            <p>
                                УЗО е самостојо рамноправно и легитимно тело составено од активни, мотивирани и амбициозни ученици, кое на демократски
                                начин е вклучено во носењето одлуки во соработка со училишните служби.
                            </p>
                        </div></div></div></div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on("resize", function (e) {
        checkScreenSize();
    });

    checkScreenSize();

    function checkScreenSize() {
        var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();
        if (newWindowWidth < 768) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.hero-overlay-block-1').click(function () {
                    $('.block-uzo').slideToggle("slow");
                    $('block-uzo').css('display', 'block');;
                    $('.block-more-1').hide();
                    $('.block-misija').hide();
                    $('.block-vizija').hide();
                });
            });
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.hero-overlay-block-2').click(function () {
                    $('.block-misija').toggle("slow");
                    $('.block-misija').css('display', 'block');;
                    $('.block-more-2').hide();
                    $('.block-uzo').hide();
                    $('.block-vizija').hide();
                });
            });
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.hero-overlay-block-3').click(function () {
                    $('.block-vizija').toggle("slow");
                    $('block-vizija').css('display', 'block');;
                    $('.block-more-3').hide();
                    $('.block-uzo').hide();
                    $('.block-misija').hide();
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i don't speak russian.

Comment: @iHasCodeForU It's not russian, it's Macedonian website but never mind, I am not asking of you to read the text, can you solve my problem, so I can close a div on second click. For solving the problem you don't need to understand the text just the code

Comment: @VictorGavrilovic The other language in this question makes us unsure if there's important information in that language that we're missing. Also you seem to be omitting some code. A jsfiddle would be a useful step into improving this question. As is, we're unsure of the problem.

Comment: You may need a different event type for mobile, such as `tap`: https://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't speak russian but I will try my best..

It seems that you are registering too much click handlers and getting an unexpected behaviour.

On `$(window).on("resize", function (e) { checkScreenSize(); }` you're calling your `checkScreenSize` function everytime you resize your window, and inside this function you are registering a click handler for every hero element again, and again, and again if your resolution is lower than 768 (this is why you're having problems only on mobile).

What I think you're looking for is something like this:

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hero-overlay-block-1').click(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            $('.block-uzo').slideToggle("slow");
            $('block-uzo').css('display', 'block');
            $('.block-more-1').hide();
            $('.block-misija').hide();
            $('.block-vizija').hide();
        }
    });
    $('.hero-overlay-block-2').click(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            $('.block-misija').toggle("slow");
            $('.block-misija').css('display', 'block');
            $('.block-more-2').hide();
            $('.block-uzo').hide();
            $('.block-vizija').hide();
        }
    });
    $('.hero-overlay-block-3').click(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            $('.block-vizija').toggle("slow");
            $('block-vizija').css('display', 'block');
            $('.block-more-3').hide();
            $('.block-uzo').hide();
            $('.block-misija').hide();
        }
    });
});`

This way you register a click handler once for each hero element. The screen resolution is checked only when the click events are triggered.

Sorry if I didn't understand the problem properly, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work, the 2nd div pops up but I cant close it

Comment: Hi! Could you create a JSFiddle of your problem? The HTML part was difficult to understand. Have you removed the on resize handler?

Comment: I can't because the site is big, and I have a couple of JS that are needed, i can jut create html and css and i can post it so u can add JS

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/19sgu136/     There you go, if you can, please add JS so it can show the text from ".block-uzo" when I click on the first block it has to slide down under the first block and when i click again on the first block it has to dissapear the ".block-uzo"

Comment: Do you want "block-uzo" to toggle only when your screen width is bellow 768 (auto-hide it if width >= 768)? Or the "block-uzo" should also toggle when clicked on a higher screen width?
See this: https://jsfiddle.net/marciojmo/19sgu136/3/

Comment: I want to toggle when is below 768

Comment: Check it now: https://jsfiddle.net/marciojmo/19sgu136/8/
It is the same concept, I just added a window resize handler to hide the elements if the width is bigger than 768..

Comment: This works fine but I have problem with the Mobile version again because of the PC version...

Comment: Can you contact me so we can solve the problem more easily?

Comment: Or can you just tell me how to hide elements: '.block-more-1', 'block-more-2', 'block-more-3' when the width is below 768

Comment: SO can you help me make the mobile version with those divs below, I think I just have to hide '.block-more-1', 'block-more-2', 'block-more-3'  this elements, but idk how

Comment: I think I finally understand what you were trying to do. Check this out:
https://jsfiddle.net/19sgu136/12/ 
If this is not the desired behaviour I quit and I'll study macedonian. lol 
I've added a resizer function that swaps between the desktop and mobile extra info. There is probably an easier way of doing this using css media queries..

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wanted hahahah Thank You very much, btw I don't know how to create it with css media queries

Comment: When i go to inspect elements then in console there is one erroe, and it says Unexpected token var